# Can I install a software on my work laptop, not knowing the admin password?

Tags: node.js

Not trying to break any rules, The managers allowed me to take my work laptop home and I'm trying to install a software. The person who has the admin password is in a holiday and won't come back for a while. Is there any way I could find her password out or install a software on windows 10 without it? 
 Any ideas?

I've already tried doing the .bat file and rendering the setup through it -->

```
cmd /min /C "set __COMPAT_LAYER=RUNASINVOKER && start "" "%1""
```

It didn't work. I still get the user and password request.

Comment: SO isn't the place to ask about password cracking. Searching the web for "node windows install without admin access" would the the logical first place to start--not here. Unrelated, but a place where a single person knows the admin password is a place just waiting for disaster.

Answer (score -1):

You can just make a bootable usb with "syslinux" tool, this is a password breaking tool for windows operating systems. Just plug in and break administrator password, then you can be able to install any kind of software which needs administrative privileges.

If you are interested in having tool, just feel free to contact me